# Junk mail is recognized, but not filtered

Tags: thunderbird, spam-prevention

I've already posted this question on the Mozilla Thunderbird forum, and the people who responded were unable to figure out what is happening. I hope I'll have better luck here!

I'm using Thunderbird 17.0 under Windows 7.

A couple of days ago I tried to resolve a long-standing irritation by getting Thunderbird's junk filter to work.

With the default settings, Thunderbird apparently was recording the addresses of messages that I marked as junk, because the "Junk" button ceased to appear for messages from those addresses. However, nothing was ever recorded in the junk mail log or moved to Junk.

I read the main help topic for the junk mail feature, then set the filter options as follows.

```
Options > Security > Junk
   [x] When I mark messages as junk:
      (x) Move them to the account's "Junk" folder.
      ( ) Delete them
   [ ] Mark messages determined to be Junk as read
   [x] Enable adaptive junk filter logging.

Options > Account Settings > (for each account) > Junk Settings
   [x] Enable adaptive junk mail controls for this account
   Do not automatically mark mail as junk if address is in:
      [ ] Colleccted Addresses
      [ ] Eudora Nicknames
      [x] Personal Address Book


   [ ] Trust junk mail headers set by

   [x] Move new junk messages to:
      (x) "Junk" folder on: Local Folders
      ( ) Other: Junk on lLocal Folders
      [ ] Automatically delete junk mail older than 14 days
```

Thunderbird now detects junk mail and records it in the log, but still does not move it to the Junk folder. What have I missed?

Comment: Hmm Thunderbird does the same sometimes for me, when the number of e-mails in the target folder has reached a certain limit. I am using IMAP, even for the junk folder, so this could be IMAP related. Anyway, clean up your junk folder, compress it and try again.